# Is there a MySQL database schema for an unknown number of dimensions?

Tags: mysql, database

[Star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) and [snoflake schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema) are common schemas to store multidimensional data in relational databases like MySQL. In both schemas the number of dimensions is known beforehand. One can just create as many tables for as many dimensions as needed. But what if I do not know how many dimensions my database will store? It is more than two and less than infinity. What if the number of dimensions changes over time and I cannot afford to modify the schema on the go?

Has anyone dealt with a similar problem before? Is there some standard relational multidimensional database schema for unspecified number of dimensions akin [snoflake schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema)?

Comment: In a normalized environment the number of dimensions would rearely be 'unknown'. I mean, you may add a few tables as you go along, but you wouldn't be endlessly adding tables. That said, while an EAV is a pain to work with, it can be useful where atrributes are constantly being added.

Comment: @Strawberry It is really unknown though :) A safe bet would be to say its no more than 1000. But most of the data might only have 2-4 dimensions and I wouldn't want each row to carry any empty cells for "unused" dimensions.

Comment: So take a look at an EAV model. If you do decide to pursue that route, I would say generate a table for each data type.